# Paste command skipped in vim script to move selection of lines to end of file?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to script a simple set of vim commands, and can use this sequence of commands interactively to do what I want.  For example, given the following file contents

```
#if 0
#include "foo.h"
#include "goo.h"
a <<< HERE >>>
b
c
#endif
```

when positioned on the line 'a', after the #include lines, I can do:

```
:,/endif/-1 d
:$
:p
:w
```

However, when I put these commands in a file ('a_vim_script'), and run:

```
:source a_vim_script
```

vim reports:

```
3 fewer lines
"f" 5L, 68C written
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

and produces:

```
#if 0
#include "foo.h"
#include "goo.h"
#endif
```

instead of what I get when I do these commands interactively:

```
#if 0
#include "foo.h"
#include "goo.h"
#endif
a
b
c
```

The delete, move and write commands all execute, but the paste gets skipped mysteriously?

I can do this task other ways.  For example, this script does what I want (and then moves to the next selection in my vim -q list) :

```
:,$!echo '\#endif\n' && grep -v '\#endif'
:w
:cn
```

However, why is it that the 'p' paste command in the first little vim script gets skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:p` is not short for `:put` it is short for `:print`. Please use `:put` or `:pu` for short.

Additionally you should probably be using the `:move` command instead of `:delete` and `:put`.

```
:,/endif/-m $
```

For more information see:

```
:h :p
:h :pu
:h :m
```